# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$rAFProvider

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angular-mock

Using Karma to test Angular getting error:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMock due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$rAFProvider
```

Angular mock, Angular versions error?
I've heard solutions detailing changing of angular-mock version or angular version--which seems like a bad idea since I'd like to test on the same version as the app starts with.
Anyone else have an error like this?

Comment: This is a very common error... Do not expect an answer without sharing some code. You could have a typo, forgot to include the module, etc. About `angular-mocks` version: yes, you should use the same as angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by making sure the rails asset pipeline, which provides the angular-related assets in my case, was correctly serving assets during testing.

Answer (score 7):

Please check your angular version.

Your angular version and angular-mock version must be same.

To download angular-mock go the below link and replace the X.Y.Z with your angular version and save it

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-mocks.js
```

for example my angular version is [1.2.9](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-mocks.js)

This work for me .

Comment: Thanks heaps. I wished I'd googled the error an hour ago.